# Doctrine - The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hy,
I have problem with validation and schema creation
I am creating an api via the api platform, (this is my 1st project under symfony)
I have a constraint, the database exists and I cannot touch it.

I have an headerOrder entity and an LineOrder  entity.
But the column of join are not a key.

```
class enteteCommande
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="I_ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $IId;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="C_CDE_NUMERO", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 *
 */
#[Groups(['write:commande'])]
private $CCdeNumero;
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="lignesCommande", mappedBy="enteteLigne")
 *
 */ 
private $detailLigne;


class lignesCommande
{

/**
 * @varint
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="I_IDL", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $IIdL;
 /**
 * @varstring|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="LIGNE_C_CDE_NUMERO", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $ligneCCdeNumero;


 /**
 * 
 * 
 *  @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="enteteCommande", inversedBy="detailLigne")
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="LIGNE_C_CDE_NUMERO", referencedColumnName="C_CDE_NUMERO")
 * 
 */ 
private $enteteLigne;
```

My schema :

| enteteCommande |
| --- |
| I_ID |
| C_CDE_NUMERO |

| lignesCommande |
| --- |
| I_IDL |
| LIGNE_C_CDE_NUMERO |

And error log :
The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Entity\OrderLignes'.
The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Entity\OrderEntete'.

How to make manytomany without key ?

thank !

Comment: You must have to make changes in database and need to defined id as primary key.

Comment: thank, but I have a constraint, the database exists and I cannot touch it....

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the [JoinTable](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) on the owning side of the relationship (`lignesCommande`). Not just a `JoinColumn`. If the `JoinTable` configuration is missing, Doctrine will fall back to its default `ManyToMany` configuration and try to connect `id` primary key columns, which in your case won't work.

Here's an example (but untested) `JoinTable` annotation:

```php
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(
*      targetEntity="enteteCommande",
*      inversedBy="detailLigne"
* )
* @ORM\JoinTable(
*      name="foobar",
*      joinColumns={
*          @ORM\JoinColumn(
*              name="LIGNE_C_CDE_NUMERO",
*              referencedColumnName="LIGNE_C_CDE_NUMERO"
*          ),
*      },
*      inverseJoinColumns={
*          @ORM\JoinColumn(
*              name="C_CDE_NUMERO",
*              referencedColumnName="C_CDE_NUMERO"
*          ),
*      }
* )
*/
private $enteteLigne;
```

Comment: Thank ! only on lignesCommande ?  I tested and I still have an error message The referenced column name 'C_CDE_NUMERO' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class